# When does GC remove objects that have only weak references?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a java application "with history" and it uses WeakReferences for caching. I made several heapdumps and saw that all of them contains a lot of objects with weak references (10%-15% of heap size, ~1.2GB).

- Does it mean that weak references produce memory pressure on JVM?
- And forces a FullGC with stop-the-world pauses?

P.S. I know that WeakReference produces performance penalty for GC for CMS, because it makes algorithm harder. But did somebody see a paper or some official information about it? I found only this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250502/cost-of-using-weak-references-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

Object Computing, Inc. did a presentation on this that I've found useful in the past.  Here's an excerpt:

> Kinds of Object References
>
> - Strong references
> - SoftReference
> - GC’ed any time after there are no strong references to the referent, but is typically retained until memory is low
> - can be used to implement caches of objects that can be recreated if needed
>
> WeakRefernence
>
> - GC’ed any time after there are no strong or soft references to the referent
> - often used for “canonical mappings” where each object
>     has a unique identifier (one-to-one), and in collections of “listeners”
>
> "For soft and weak references, the get returns null method when the referent object has been GC’ed."

SOURCE: http://java.ociweb.com/mark/other-presentations/JavaGC.pdf

That seems to suggest **SoftReference** is the go to choice for cached objects.

In practice I have used Guava caching APIs and let it manage the details:
https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't answer on my question :) For cache I prefer [Encache](http://www.ehcache.org), because it has a lot of options, Beans, statistics, etc. But in case of this topic I'm interesting in question **when** GC removes objects with WeakReference.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it mean that weak references produce memory pressure on JVM?

No. Weak references don't affect GC at all. They just give you a way to track it.

> And forces a FullGC with stop-the-world pauses?

No.

Comment: So from GC performance perspective there is no difference between using and not using WeakReference? And removing WeakReference doesn't increase performance?

Comment: And do you know when GC cleans up object with WeakReference? For example, in CMS algorithm.

Comment: I've already answered your first question. The answer to the second question is basically 'whenever it likes'.